# Unique HTML element IDs for each model with Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I've got django models displaying on a page using a checkbox input that has a label over it like so:

```
{% if recipes_list %}
<table>
{% for r in recipes_list %}
<tr>
  <td>
    <section class="ac-container">
      <div>
        <input id="ac-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-1">{{r.name}}</label>
        <article class="ac-small">
        <ul>
        {% for i in r.ingredient_list%}
          <li>{{i.part}}, {{i.amount}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
 </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

When I click on the label of each entry in `recipes_list`, it obviously always opens the article of the first one. I've been looking around for solutions for the past couple days on how to give a unique id in the html for each model entry, but I can't find anything that works with this situation. I've tried forms, model forms, various javascript, and php. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to give unique id's exactly to what tag element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a filter which gets the model name

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='class_name')
def class_name(obj):
  return obj.__class__.__name__
```

and in the template:

and in the template, wherever you want the id/classname:

```
<article id={{obj|class_name}}>
  {# further code #}
</article>
```

## OR

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #fields

    def class_name(self):
        return "%s"%self.__class__.__name__ #returns the model instance name
```

If you want to return the instance name:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def class_name(self):
        return "%s"%(slugify(self.name)) #or whatever field has the specific instance name
```

and in the template:

```
{{obj.class_name}}
```

Comment: This seems to only return the name of the class of the model (in that example, "MyModel"). For what I was looking for at least, I'd want the model instance name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) to achieve this:

```
{% if recipes_list %}
<table>
{% for r in recipes_list %}
<tr>
  <td>
    <section class="ac-container">
      <div>
        <input id="ac-{{forloop.counter}}" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-{{forloop.counter}}">{{r.name}}</label>
        <article id="article-{{forloop.counter}}" class="ac-small">
        <ul>
        {% for i in r.ingredient_list%}
          <li>{{i.part}}, {{i.amount}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
 </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wasn't aware you could access the counter in the for loop. That was the first thing I looked for too!

Comment: You can, you can also access a parent loop counter as well. Take a look at the built-in template tags doc, you'll find useful stuff there :)

Answer (score 3):

Its simple use object primary key as id because its unique (unless you have another loop from another model):

```
{% for r in recipes_list %}
    <input id="ac-{{ r.id }}" type="checkbox" />
{% endfor %}
```

Or use `forloop.counter`:

```
{% for r in recipes_list %}
    <input id="ac-{{ forloop.counter }}" type="checkbox" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works great, but I like karthik's answer where you get an explicit, useful id for each element based off of the model instance name.